# Apache Ignite Application to load database table?

Tags: ignite

How can I create a maven project in java to load an Oracle database table on the Apache Ignite server?
Also, I'm supposed to create the project on my local machine while Apache Ignite runs on a remote machine to which I have SSH connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use Ignite Web Console](https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/ignite-web-console) to do that. There is a [public Ignite Web Console](https://console.gridgain.com/) hosted by GridGain.

It will ask you to download Ignite Web Console Agent, connect to your Oracle database, analyze your data structure and output a zipped Maven project with data load functionality out of box (via `loadCache`).

Deployment of the project to remote machine is out of scope of this excercise.